# How to disable one form control from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing windows forms application.I placed a button in groupbox.If I clicked that button, second form need to be displayed and is loading perfectly.But if I clicked on that groupbox area,the second form is hiding.How to make that groupbox as disable after second form is loaded?. Please refer my code below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     form2 myform = new form2();
     myform.Show();
     groupBox1.Enabled = false;  
}
```

Comment: If you do `myForm.ShowDialog()` instead of `myform.Show()` does that give you the behavior you are looking for? Note: the code will pause at the `ShowDialog()` line and no code below it will be run till after you close `form2`.

Comment: It is not clear why you would consider clicking the Groupbox.  Maybe the code is just too slow and you get bored?  Never make a user wait.  Use the Show(owner) overload to ensure that the window is always on top.

Comment: if the groupbox is on the calling form..then set the groupBox1.Enabled = false before calling the myform.ShowDialog()();

Comment: @Hans: I tried your suggestion and it is working fine.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Scott: I tried your code and is also working fine.But I am unable to close the form in which groupbox is located. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Ok, so you don't want `ShowDialog`, I would recommend you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34995544/edit) and add a few more sentances explaining the behavior you want to have.

Answer (score 2):

So, just to conclude the comments.

Use the [Form.Show(IWin32Window owner)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

> You can use this method to display a non-modal form. When you use this method, the Owner property of the form is set to owner. The non-modal form can use the Owner property to get information about the owning form. Calling this method is identical to setting the Owner property of the non-modal and then calling the Show() method.

Full code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     form2 myform = new form2();
     myform.Show(this);
     groupBox1.Enabled = false;  
}
```